# Replacement of Self-tracking entities in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6, self-tracking-entities, .net-4.5

I am sure most of .NET developers must be facing this issue one way or the other. The problem is simple, I am upgrading my project from **.NET 4 to .NET 4.5.1**. So far so good the upgrade went neatly. But when I upgraded from EF4 to EF6, I did encounter lot of bugs in my queries. Some of these were related to renaming the context which I did, but as for the errors related to **Self-tracking entities**, I am a little confused.

**Self-tracking entities** are a major part of my project and EF6 not supporting them means I will have to rewrite a major part of my **DAL**. I tried to find out but have not been able to find any alternative to STE in EF6.

**Does anyone know way around to this scenario?** Will I have to rewrite my STE dependent Queries. The answers should not include explanations on why Microsoft decided to put STEs behind as I have already gone through many blogs explaining that.

Comment: What did you wind up doing to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project called [Trackable Entities](https://trackable.codeplex.com/) that provides support for STEs in EF6.0

Here is a [blog post](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2013/11/18/trackable-entities-versus-self-tracking-entities/) comparing Trackable Entities to STEs.